# Why can anyone use this command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Anyone who runs /purge can delete messages in the server. They do not have the "manage_messages" permission.

```
@client.tree.command(name="purge")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def purge(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Purged {amount} messages.")
```

I want it to only work if someone has the permission "manage_messages". This used to work with prefix commands but now it doesn't work with slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's no longer a `@discord.ext.commands.Bot.command` and is now a `@discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command()` which has a different permission check of using [@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions)

```
from discord import app_commands
#rest of imports

@client.tree.command(name="purge")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def purge(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Purged {amount} messages.")
```

Comment: I just get the error "AttributeError: module 'discord.app_commands' has no attribute 'has_permissions'. Did you mean: 'default_permissions'?". app_commands is already imported as well.

Comment: Apologies, I have miss typed `@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions()` as `@discord.app_commands.has_permissions()` in the code

Comment: Ok this works for the permissions. My new issue is that only 1 message can be purged or else the interaction will fail.

Comment: That is a completely different problem. Accept this answer, close this question and  make a new question with specific details of your new issue.